# Mens. error INSERT SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

he configurado un usuario con permiso INSERT para tabla Clientes : GRANT INSERT ON CLIENTES TO usuarioX

ejecutando la query :

[image: consulta insert]

me devuelve el siguiente aviso:

---

Mens. 102, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 1 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

(1 filas afectadas)

---

En la tabla se inserta la línea correctamente, para comprobar que no es fallo de sintaxis cuando ejecuto la misma consulta con el usuario 'sa' se inserta y no devuelve ningún error

como lo puedo solucionar ??..

Comment: Quieres decir que la misma consulta (exactamente), al ejecutarla (desde donde? linea de comando?) con el usuario 'sa' funciona bien y con el otro usuario tira ese mensaje (pero igual inserta el registro?) Estas seguro?

Comment: Hay algún trigger en la tabla `CLIENTES`?

Comment: comprobaré el tema de trigger...

Comment: @brahim debes agregar tu query para decirte específicamente donde se encuentra el problema.

Comment: sobre tu pregunta "leonbloy" : si se inserta correctamente ademas lo indica al final del mensaje de error (1 filas afectadas)

Comment: consulta :

 INSERT INTO CLIENTES (CODCLIENTE,CODCONTABLE,NOMBRECLIENTE,CODPOSTAL,POBLACION,PROVINCIA,PAIS,TELEFONO1,E_MAIL,TIPOPORTES,RIESGOCONCEDIDO, TIPO,RECARGO,FACTURARSINIMPUESTOS,REGIMFACT,CODMONEDA,FECHANACIMIENTO,NIF20,CONDENTREGAEDI,CONDENTREGA,CODPAIS,MOBIL) 
VALUES (100089856,430000000030,'Manuel','27003','LEÓN - PONFERRADA','LEÓN - PONFERRADA','ESPAÑA','666666666','xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com','D',0,0,'F','F','G',2,'1992-08-04','xxxxxxxxxxE','X2','EP','ES','666666666')
go

la consulta es correcta porque no devuelve ningún error cuando la ejecuto con "sa".

Comment: LAMAK : aparte de los Triggers que puede afectar a esta consulta?

y que hay que hacer si tiene triggers ? 

se trata de una base de datos de un programa CRM bastante grande.. estoy buscando todas las opciones que puedan afectar..

Comment: @brahim la consulta realmente tiene esas barras verticales insertadas entre medio? (`|`), porque eso no es correcto

Answer (score 1):

Este mensaje de error:

> Mens. 102, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 1 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Se refiere a que posiblemente tienes mal cerrado algún string en tu consulta o tienes algún caracter, lo cual puede provocar que se corte tu query.

En este caso tienes caracteres no imprimibles, puedes verlo aquí :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: o sea, puede ser un string mal cerrado u otro error de sintaxis. Además se debe considerar lo extraño de que el dato sí se inserte (según dice la pregunta)

Comment: En tu caso son estos caracteres: | , trata escribiendo nuevamente el query.

Comment: Sí, esa es mi sospecha, por eso pregunté en un comentario si es que la consulta realmente tiene esas barras verticales. Y es exactamente por eso que digo que el error puede ser un string mal cerrado u otro motivo

Comment: Deben ser esos caracteres el problema, aunque me parece extraño que con un usuario se ejecute correctamente el query y con otro no,

Comment: Como decía, en efecto creo que ese es el problema, pero tu respuesta sigue diciendo: `Se refiere a que tienes mal cerrado algún string en tu consulta`, lo que no parece ser el motivo

Comment: Hola hace unas horas habia editado mi respuesta, y era una de las causas, no la causa.

Comment: la consulta que he copiado no tiene barras, no sé porque os sale así..

la misma consulta funciona correctamente con usuario 'sa' !! no puede ser de sintaxis..

Comment: he editado la pregunta inicial, he puesto una foto de la consulta..

Comment: @brahim Sin embargo, nunca respondiste sobre si tiene algún trigger o no

Answer (score 0):

Buenos días,

gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda..

tras revisar todas las posibilidades que habéis comentado: Triggers, sintaxis ..etc. todo esta correcto y no hay triggers que puedan afectar a estos permisos. he probado eliminar y volver a dar varias veces el permiso de INSERT al usuario y el día siguiente me ha funcionado a la primera sin ningún error con la misma consulta.. no se ha reiniciado el servicio de SQL ni nada.. no puedo dar explicación de la solución porque no tiene sentido el error inicial.

Saludos.